# PHP: session value destroy after use

Tags: php, session

I have a problem. I have 2 php-scripts. When the first one succesfully runs I want it to redirect to the second using header(), but I want the second page to know that the first script has been succesfully executed.
So I was thinking of putting something in $_SESSION at the end of script 1, for exampe:

```
$_SESSION['succes'] = 'U have succesfully executed the script';
```

Now on the second page I just check if there is something in $_SESSION['succes'] and if there is I show it via HTML. To make sure the succes-message gets only displayed once I delete it using:

```
$_SESSION['succes'] = '';
```

But this does not work. It seems like the emptying gets executed before the check? It is properly set, but not shown. When I delete the empty-command it works perfectly:

DOES NOT WORK:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['succes'])){
echo '<div id="succes">' . $_SESSION['succes'] . '</div>';
$_SESSION['succes'] = '';
}
```

DOES WORK (but now the succes gets displayed on every page after one succesfull execution):

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['succes'])){
echo '<div id="succes">' . $_SESSION['succes'] . '</div>';
//$_SESSION['succes'] = '';
}
```

I know I could use variables in my URL, but I don't want that. Otherwise users can type in the URL manually and get the succes-message unwanted.

Someone got any idea?

Comment: The word success is spelled wrong in every spot in your script. You should also try using `isset()` and `unset()` instead of setting it to a blank string.

Comment: Your first code should work. There must be more that you're not showing.

Comment: @Jessica It's spelled almost right, it's just French.

Comment: @bredikhin `'U have succesfully executed the script'` definitely isn't French.

Comment: You are using `session_start();` on every page aren't you?

Comment: @bredikhin What is "almost right"? Is that like "halfway pregnant"?

Comment: Session is started yes, I get no errors or warnings. It just doesn't work. Is has tomething to do with session values that is evaluated as empty, even when it has something in it. The only thing beïng able to do that is the second command, so the if does execute properly, but the value is emptied before it is beïng displayed.

Comment: @Jessica, using set and unset doesn't work either, was my first possible option.